# Automated BFS drawing with Lua

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, automation

I tried to learn Lua with TeX. To do so, I tried to implement BFS in such a way, that it can automatically create Tikz pictures. Here is a short example of what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force}

\begin{luacode}
    tp=tex.print
    
    bfs_initial_graph = {}
    bfs_current = {}
    bfs_visited = {}
    bfs_in_queue = {}
    bfs_unvisited = {}
    
    function bfs_init(graph, start)
        -- initialize bfs_current with start node
        bfs_current = {start}
    
        -- initialize bfs_visited as an empty set
        bfs_visited = {}
    
        -- initialize bfs_in_queue with nodes reachable from start node
        bfs_in_queue = {}
        for _, neighbor in ipairs(graph[start]) do
            table.insert(bfs_in_queue, neighbor)
        end
    
        bfs_unvisited = {}
            for node, neighbors in pairs(graph) do
                if node ~= start then
                table.insert(bfs_unvisited, node)
            end
        end
    end
    
    function bfs_step()
        -- check if bfs_in_queue is empty
        if #bfs_in_queue == 0 then
            return false
        end
        -- move current node from bfs_current to bfs_visited
        local current_node = table.remove(bfs_current, 1)
        table.insert(bfs_visited, current_node)
        
        -- move first node from bfs_in_queue to bfs_current
        local next_node = table.remove(bfs_in_queue, 1)
        table.insert(bfs_current, next_node)
        
        -- update bfs_unvisited and bfs_in_queue
        for _, neighbor in ipairs(bfs_initial_graph[next_node]) do
            if bfs_unvisited[neighbor] then
                bfs_unvisited[neighbor] = nil
                table.insert(bfs_in_queue, neighbor)
            end
        end
        
        return true
    end
    
    function bfs_draw_graph()
        -- start TikZ picture
        tp("\\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={circle, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}]")
        
        -- loop through nodes in the initial graph and draw them
        for node, neighbors in pairs(bfs_initial_graph) do
            -- determine color based on BFS list membership
            local color = "gray"
            if node == bfs_current[1] then
                color = "red"
            elseif table.contains(bfs_in_queue, node) then
                color = "yellow"
            elseif table.contains(bfs_visited, node) then
                color = "green"
            end
        
            -- draw node with appropriate color
            tp(string.format("%s [color=%s]", node, color))
        
            -- draw edges to neighbors
            for _, neighbor in ipairs(neighbors) do
                tp(string.format("%s -- %s", node, neighbor))
            end
        end
        -- end TikZ picture
        tp("\\end{tikzpicture}")
    end
    
    function bfs_run()
        -- run BFS until bfs_in_queue is empty
        while #bfs_in_queue > 0 do
            bfs_next_step()
        end
    end
\end{luacode}

\newcommand{\BfsInit}[2]{\luaexec{bfs_init(#1, #2)}}
\newcommand{\BfsNextStep}{\luaexec{bfs_draw_graph()}}
\newcommand{\BfsAllSteps}{\luaexec{bfs_run()}}

\begin{document}

    \BfsInit{
            a -- {b,c},
            b -- {a,c},
            c -- {a,b},}
            {a}
            
    \BfsNextStep

\end{document}
```

Sadly it does not run and I don't know how to get it to run. For me, a very beginner, it looks correct and I don't know where the error is. Can someone help me get in running and explain to me, where my errors are? Thank you very much!!!

Comment: A guess: Place all nodes first before you draw the edges, `\graph {a [color=green], a -- b, b [color = red]};` will not make `b` red because it was first “discovered” by the graphs library in the statement before and then its options are fixed. That said, I can't find `\graph` being produced by the Lua code nor any graphdrawong algorithm selected.

Comment: But I guess, the real problem is the Lua of it all. Is `a -- {a,c}, b -- {a,c}, c -- {a,b},` even a valid Lua statement (especially with `--` in it)? Just because the `graphs` library of TikZ uses it (which is parsed by TeX and doesn't use Lua) doesn't mean that Lua does and understands it.

Comment: Maybe you got more luck using `forest` and adjust [one of the answers here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332300).

Comment: If you say `\luaexec{bfs_init(#1, #2)}` and `#1` is `a -- {a,c}, b -- {a,c}, c -- {a,b},` (with line breaks even) and `#2` is `a`, the result would be `bfs_init(a -- {a,c}, b -- {a,c}, c -- {a,b},, a)`, which is hardly something that lua can parse, I would guess. Wouldn't you need to convert the arguments into strings or something else that lua can parse?

Comment: @JasperHabicht I was wondering about that, too. But, ignoring the `,,`, it wouldn't surprise me if there's a construct that would allow it seeing that [other languages like C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_variable_arguments.htm) and R allow a variable number of arguments. Though, it seems improbable for an argument that's not the last.